# CSS transition not working but property change is working

Tags: html, css

I am currently developing a css for a website I will publish soon ,I took so much time in the navigation bar, I am trying to make a navigation bar without using images and make it fit into users screen, and after I done it, I have a problem, I want the sub list items to drop down smothley in 2 seconds instead of poping directly

this is the CSS and the HTML
I done the transition property in .nav ul li ul li  and want it to change after 2 seconds in .nav ul li:hover ul li

be gentle on me, this is my first website that I am developing from scratch :)

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 width: 100%;
}
.pageHeader {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 960px;
 padding: 0px;
 /* [disabled]margin-top: auto;
*/
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: auto;
*/
 float: none;
}
.pageHeader a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 position: absolute;
 float: right;
 bottom: 50px;
}
.homeContent {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 top: 105px;
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: 960px;
 background-color: green;
 z-index: -1;
}

/* Navigation */
/* the nav div blue background color and cyan border top */
.nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 max-height:50px;
 border-top: 4px solid rgb(0,160,170);
 background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
 /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */

 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(0,110,201,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}


.nav ul {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}



.nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 border-left: 1px solid gray;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 font-family: amatic-sc;
}


.nav ul li:first-child {
 border-left: 0px;
}


/* buttons/ links */
.nav ul li a {
 height: 20px;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(251,251,251, .3);
}



.nav ul li a:hover {
 background: rgb(20,155,153); /* Old browsers */
 /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(20,155,153,1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(0,110,201,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#149b99', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
 color: #fff;
}
.nav ul li a:active {
 color: #D1D1D1;
}



/* Nav 2nd level*/

.nav ul li ul {
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.80);
 border-left: 1px solid rgb(0,160,170);
 border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,160,170);
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,160,170);
}
.nav ul li ul li {
 float: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 border: 0px;
 font-color: black;
 max-height: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: max-height 2s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease 0s;
 -ms-transition: max-height 2s ease 0s;
 transition: max-height 2s ease 0s;

}
.nav ul li ul li a {
 height: 15px;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
 z-index: 100;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul {
 display:block;
 
}

.nav ul li:hover ul li{
 max-height:999px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/style_screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="mainPaegHeader" class="pageHeader"><img src="img/logo.gif" width="318" height="106" alt=""/>
<a href="">العربية</a>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.htm">Second Link</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.htm">Third Link</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">sub Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.htm">More links</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.htm">More links</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.htm">More links</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.htm">More links</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="homeContent" id="pageContent">Content for  class "homeContent" id "pageContent" Goes Here</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a section in your transition property for height.

Comment: It did not work
I also tried transition: all 2s ease 0s;
the property change works but not the transition

Comment: Since you are using `display` to show your nested list, you cannot animate it's appearance. `display` is not an animateable property as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: Thank you, I tried removing display property it worked!, the problem now is I want to hide the list items content if its not on :hover mode and if I :hover I show the content and use transition property

Comment: it seems it works with visibility:visible; fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help and effort
it was small simple mistake mentioned by skube
I was using display with transition and that is invaild, it disables animation
so I used visible property with transition instead
    visibility: hidden;
    visibility: visible;
I changed some css properties in order for that to work, here is the css file after the fixes

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.pageHeader {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* [disabled]margin-top: auto;
*/
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /* [disabled]margin-bottom: auto;
*/
    float: none;
}
.pageHeader a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.homeContent {
    position:relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Navigation */
/* the nav div blue background color and cyan border top */
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height:50px;
    border-top: 4px solid rgb(0,160,170);
    background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(0,110,201,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}


.nav ul {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



.nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: amatic-sc;
}


.nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0px;
}


/* buttons/ links */
.nav ul li a {
    height: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(251,251,251, .3);
}



.nav ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(20,155,153); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(20,155,153,1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(0,110,201,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(20,155,153,1) 0%, rgba(0,110,201,1) 99%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#149b99', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color: #fff;
}
.nav ul li a:active {
    color: #D1D1D1;
}



/* Nav 2nd level*/
.nav ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    max-height: 0px;
}
.nav ul li ul li{
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 0px;
    font-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    max-height: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;



}
.nav ul li ul li a {
    height: 12px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(0,160,170);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,160,170);
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.80);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    z-index: 100;
}
.nav ul li ul li:last-child a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,160,170);}

.nav ul li:hover ul {
    max-height:999px;
    visibility:visible;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul li{
    max-height:999px;}
```